# Kusto | Azure Data Explorer | extractjson() returns nothing

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to use the extractjson() function in Kusto/Azure Data Explorer. I read in the MS documentation that when you need to extract more than one element of a JSON compound object it's better to use parse_json(), but in my scenario I just need to extract one value from the JSON, so I'm assuming that conversely it would be best to use extractjson(). Here is a sample table to illustrate:

```
let T = datatable (myObject:string)[
    '[{"Id":1,"Value":"light saber"}]',
    '[{"Id":2,"Value":"jedi beacon"}]'
];
T
| extend JediTools = extractjson("$.Value", myObject)
```

On the last line I am attempting to extend a column to contain the extracted json values, but instead I get nothing:
[image: actual output from extractjson() function]

Expected results:

[image: expected output from extractjson() function]

The function must be finding "Value" because it's not throwing an error, but **why is the column blank where it should show the extracted values?** I also tried the following but the result is the same:

`| extend JediTools = extractjson("$.Value", myObject, typeof(string))`

`| extend JediTools = tostring(extractjson("$.Value", myObject))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually does not find the "Value" property, because it is enclosed in an array. When an json property is not found you get back a null value, not an error. Since you have an array, you need to "mv-expand" it:

```
let T = datatable (myObject:string)[
    '[{"Id":1,"Value":"light saber"}]',
    '[{"Id":2,"Value":"jedi beacon"}]'
];
T
| extend myObject = todynamic(myObject)
| mv-expand myObject 
| extend JediTools = myObject.Value
```

Comment: Thanks Avnera, excellent explanation. In playing around with this I found that if I remove the square brackets (array notation) then extractjson() works. Also note to anyone else implementing this solution I was able to use parse_json() in place of todynamic, they seem to be the same thing.